# Qt class undefined, header included

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am working with Qt in Visual Studio and having some problems using specific classes.

For once I do not know why I am unable to simply include a module like `#include <QtSql>`, but I have to include the specific Header like `#include <QtSql/qsqlquery.h>`, even though I added the path to additional libraries and of course the modules are also activated in the Qt Project Settings.

But nevertheless, it is still no problem to work with that. But now I wanted to create a 3D Surface Plot from the `<QtDataVisualization/q3dsurface.h>` Header, included it like all the others, but `Q3DSurface` is not available as a type for me to use.

Is there something else I have to take care of when using 3D Visualization?

Comment: From what I recall the `QtDataVisualization` classes are placed in their own namespace so you might want to try `QtDataVisualization::Q3DSurface`.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, that was exactly the problem!